# What makes a transaction not mined and stay in txpool?

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, gas, gas-price, txpool

What Makes a transaction in txPool not mined ?

Answer (score 1):

Miners generally mine transactions that will pay them the highest gas fee for doing so. Because of this, each block is a sort of auction where the highest bidders (in terms of `gasPrice`) get included in the block.

A transaction sitting in the txPool generally means that the supplied `gasPrice` is not high enough for a miner to want to accept it. You can check [here](https://ethgasstation.info/) for current gas prices.

If you want to speed up this process, simply resend the transaction and choose a higher `gasPrice`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the problem that I am using a private network (PoA) and all transactions are sent with the same gasPrice (3000000)